# How to control the CSS on an Active/Focused button in Foundation 5

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I have created a `CMS` based on the `Foundation 5` front end platform. In it I have created a CSS generator which basically allows for a SASS type control over the entire stylesheet through administration on a live site.

The system works great, however, I cannot find how to control the `box shadow` style which appears on an `active/focused button`. This is the code which generates the styles for a `focused button` in my generator which was taken straight from Foundation Stylesheet:

```
$code .= 'button:hover, button:focus, .button:hover, .button:focus{';
    $code .= 'background-color: '.changeColor($primary, $primary_hover_percent).';';
    $code .= 'border-color: '.changeColor($primary, $primary_border_percent_hovered).';';
    $code .= 'color: '.$primary_font_color_hovered.';';
    $code .= '}';
```

By default Foundation applies the Primary Color as a `box shadow` on a `focused button`. My problem is I cannot find where this is taking place. As the `box shadow` property is not in this section of their stylesheet I am assuming that it is controlled by javascript.

I have searched the through the javascript but can't seem to find any code controlling the addition of the `box shadow`. Though I am sure it is a pretty simple solution, the answer alludes me. any assistance is greatly appreciated.

## Sample

[image]

The right button is the active/focused button... if you look closely you can see the blue box shadow.

## A better view

[image]

## Update

I have isolated the hexcode for the blue color and have conducted a search for the color on both the stylesheet to no avail and have searched all js files hoping to find an `addClass()` with a class such as `.active` and the like to no avail as well. Again, any thoughts on the matter are greatly welcomed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "active" or "focused"? As in being hovered over?

Comment: when the button is clicked a box shadow appears which is the same color as the primary color from the download. I am using the button to open a hidden form on the click with jquery. When clicked the shadow appears and remains there until the focus shifts to an input or other area on the page. The problem is the default color which comes with the download may not be compatible with whatever color the user had change to through the generator.

Comment: I'm not aware that Foundation 5 had any default styles for `buttons` with `:focus` or `:active`. For that matter, `:focus` is only meant for elements that require input from the user. The only thing I've ever seen by default is the `:hover` effect. Must have thrown some `SASS` in there somewhere by accident mate.

Comment: I have not used `SASS` on this project at all. I downloaded the the style sheet and rewrote each line into the generator as shown above. The `js` is `foundation.min.js`. I'm pretty baffled over it.

Comment: // $button-bg-color: $primary-color;
// $button-bg-hover: scale-color($button-bg-color, $lightness: $button-function-factor); These lines are the only thing I can think of that may relate to what you're talking about. They can be found roughly line 460ish in the _settings.scss file.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look in the `_settings.scss`. When you do a direct download without sass the stylesheet already has the hex code in place for each setting according to whatever colors you select at the time of the download. This was circumvented as I went through each line of code to place it in the generator. I'm thinking it is related to javascript somewhere. I added a pic to show what is occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learn something new every day...Come to find out this issue had nothing to do with any `Foundation 5` code. The Blue shadow was a browser setting in `Chrome` set on`:focus` for accessibility reasons. In `Firefox` the browser applies a dashed border.

Information concerning this issue can be found here:

http://outlinenone.com/

## Resolution:

The CSS Property is: `outline`

To resolve the issue I simply added `outline-style: none;` to the code above.